# How to get the DateTime when the current process started?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, build-process

How to get the DateTime when the current process started?

Comment: Do you wish to use this INSIDE of that application? Or in some other application? Or in Visual Studio? the ..... doesn't help very much.

Comment: what do you understand by "current process"?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The [`StartTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.starttime.aspx) property on the `Process` type is returning that value:

```
Process.GetCurrentProcess().StartTime
```

This can of course be used to pick up the start time of other processes as well:

```
Process p = Process.GetProcessesByName("Notepad").FirstOrDefault();
if (p != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(p.StartTime);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You will need the Process Class found in System.Diagnostics.

```
using System.Diagnostics;
```

then a function like this will suffice.

```
public DateTime GetStartTime()
{
    return Process.GetCurrentProcess().StartTime;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think what you need is [Process.StartTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.starttime.aspx).

Answer (score -2):

I think we can also

```
static DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
```

As someone posted and then deleted

Comment: Very, very fragile. You have no guarantees that will run before any other static initializers, so that can actually be *a lot* different from the real value. Also, static initializers are run only when its containing type is referenced, which is another source of problems.